# Use gradle plugin cargo to deploy to tomcat manager with non-standard name

Tags: tomcat, gradle, cargo

For security reasons we have to rename our manager app in tomcat. I am trying to deploy war files using cargo. I can get it to work when I rename the manager app back to its original name but I can't find a configuration option that would allow me to specify a different name for the manager app.
  I get the feeling that if the option exists it is something that is passed through the gradle plugin and set on the underlying ant or maven implementation. 
 I did see a build property called cargo.tomcat.manager property but I don't understand how to work with that, especially if I'm already setting the hostname and port with other configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I worked some more on this today and found that you can do it if you upgrade the plugin to the latest version (at least 1.0+), this won't be available on maven central, instead use jcentral.
 Then you can do something like:

```
    containerProperties {
        property 'cargo.remote.uri', 'http://localhost:8080/my-custom-manager'
    }
```

in the remote{} section of your cargo config in your build.gradle file.